# Как узнать текущий размер стека функций в памяти, для лучшего контроля внутри кода?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Работаю над оптимизацией кода, и столкнулся в ходе оптимизации с переполнением стека. И ситуация такова, что даже вызов procces.nextTick является дорогим, и его приходится вызывать как можно реже. В связи с чем пришлось пока поставить счетчик и сбрасывать стек с помощью procces.nextTick каждый 1000 раз. Сами понимаете, что это такое себе... Поэтому идеально знать текущий размер стека, чтобы обрубать его при, допустим, 95% заполнении.

Comment: Если возникла беда  с переполнением стека, то проблема, скорее всего, в неверной логике, и в первую очередь следует её пересмотреть.

Comment: Проблемы в логике нет, ситуация такова: что нужно парсить гиговые логи, с крошечными записями. Изначально было 1.25 миллиона вызовов чтения fs.read на ГБ лога. Я снял 95% нагрузки на CPU созданием функции кеширования, но теперь может вызваться туча callback'ов подряд без разрыва стека и тем самым вызывать переполнение стека. Подгадать параметры кеша и тд. это не лучшее решение: что если код измениться, расшириться? Файл лога будет иной?
Учитывая дороговизну process.nextTick(), было бы полезно к примеру иметь что-то подобное: getStackTrace() из JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arrayContains = Array.prototype.indexOf ?
    function(arr, val) {
        return arr.indexOf(val) > -1;
    } :
    function(arr, val) {
        for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
            if (arr[i] === val) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    };

function getCallStackSize() {
    var count = 0, fn = arguments.callee, functionsSeen = [fn];

    while ( (fn = fn.caller) && !arrayContains(functionsSeen, fn) ) {
        functionsSeen.push(fn);
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Суть интересная, но не работоспособная к сожалению. В редких случаях можно получить более менее приблизительный результат, но не более. В связи с тем, что функция будучи в рекурсии, ссылается сама на себя ".caller", нельзя узнать кто вызвал её, предшествуя перед рекурсией. А вне рекурсии нет смысла знать кол-во в стеке, ибо не достижимо. Если бы даже это и работало, была бы где нибудь ниша в отладке, но не в реальной рабочей рекурсии, ибо про производительность только молчать.

Информации наскрести не выходит, совсем. Уже даже задумываюсь об перекомпиляции nodejs с доступом к счётчику ~_~

Comment: @NewTech, [источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497112/2881286)